# undefined local variable or method `accounts' for #<NotesController:0x00000004845068>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to associate "Notes" with "Account one the same page (show.html.erb) once the note is created. However, once I create the note for the associated account I get **undefined local variable or method `accounts' for NotesController:0x0000000545e1d8"**

Notes were being created fine up until the point of association.

with  @account = accounts.find(params[:account_id]) highlighted on like 65.

```
**Parameters:** (on debug page)

    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"gm6gJ3mYDDVmDHnsB2JqhOtOY1Lc9n3P7Yuq9gpqdo4=",
     "note"=>{"comment"=>"1221211212"},
     "commit"=>"Create Note",
     "account_id"=>"1"}
```

**Running Rails 4.1.8 and
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]**

**note_colltroler.rb**

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_note, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_account
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /notes/new
  def new
    @note = note.new
  end

  # GET /notes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /notes
  # POST /notes.json
  def create
    @note = note.new(note_params)
    @note.user_id = current_user.id
    @note.account_id = @account.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.save
        format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'note was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @note }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /notes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /notes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.update(note_params)
        format.html { redirect_to account_path(@account), notice: 'note was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @note }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /notes/1
  # DELETE /notes/1.json
  def destroy
    @note.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to account_path(@account), notice: 'note was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_note
      @note = note.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_account
      @account = accounts.find(params[:account_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def note_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:comment)
    end
end
```

**note.rb**

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :account
end
```

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :program
    has_many :notes
end
```

**Rake Routes**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#destroy
           account_notes POST   /accounts/:account_id/notes(.:format)          notes#create
        new_account_note GET    /accounts/:account_id/notes/new(.:format)      notes#new
       edit_account_note GET    /accounts/:account_id/notes/:id/edit(.:format) notes#edit
            account_note PATCH  /accounts/:account_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#update
                         PUT    /accounts/:account_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#update
                         DELETE /accounts/:account_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#destroy
                accounts GET    /accounts(.:format)                            accounts#index
                         POST   /accounts(.:format)                            accounts#create
             new_account GET    /accounts/new(.:format)                        accounts#new
            edit_account GET    /accounts/:id/edit(.:format)                   accounts#edit
                 account GET    /accounts/:id(.:format)                        accounts#show
                         PATCH  /accounts/:id(.:format)                        accounts#update
                         PUT    /accounts/:id(.:format)                        accounts#update
                         DELETE /accounts/:id(.:format)                        accounts#destroy
                programs GET    /programs(.:format)                            programs#index
                         POST   /programs(.:format)                            programs#create
             new_program GET    /programs/new(.:format)                        programs#new
            edit_program GET    /programs/:id/edit(.:format)                   programs#edit
                 program GET    /programs/:id(.:format)                        programs#show
                         PATCH  /programs/:id(.:format)                        programs#update
                         PUT    /programs/:id(.:format)                        programs#update
                         DELETE /programs/:id(.:format)                        programs#destroy
             pages_index GET    /pages/index(.:format)                         pages#index
                    root GET    /                                              pages#index
```

**For Notes show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>
  <strong>First name:</strong>
  <%= @account.first_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Last name:</strong>
  <%= @account.last_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Program:</strong>
  <%= @account.program.program %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @account.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Phone:</strong>
  <%= @account.phone %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Created:</strong> 
<%= @account.created_at %>
</p>
<%= link_to "Write a Note", new_account_note_path(@account), class: "btn btn-primary" %>

  </div>
<div class="col-md-9">
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
<p><%= note.comment %></p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_account_path(@account), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', account_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
@account = accounts.find(params[:account_id])
```

try

```
@account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
```

Learn more about `.find` and other query methods [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object). Most of them are called on an

**Side Note:**

As @apneadiving pointed out, you generally want to use some sort of authorisation. I don't think you want users to be able to edit accounts of other users. With your current implementation this is possible by simply experimenting in with the account and note ids in the url (e.g. by getting `/accounts/1/notes/2/edit` any user can edit note 2 of account 1).

Consider scoping records for the current user. One approach is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186048/rails-scope-find-with-current-user).

Comment: well its too hazardous to recommend something: what if accounts should be scoped based on the current user?

Answer (score 0):

in

```
def set_account
  @account = accounts.find(params[:account_id])
end
```

`accounts` is not defined

Comment: `def set_account
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    end` Seem to correct the problem

Comment: depends so much on your setup... sometimes you need to scope depending on current user etc...